# Is there a way to autofill Pi DataLink data using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, while-loop, sampling, osisoft

I am pulling hourly data out of a server in Osisoft Pi Historian for thousands of distinct data points. The sampling function in question is PISampDat

When I try to copy one row to the next in an effort to save time and effort, I get a message to "Resize to show all values". But this message never updates to actual values when I tell the program to recalculate.

I am left with two options: A) MANUALLY enter the formula parameters for each row, a daunting and torturous task, or B) one of you can mercifully tell me how I can use VBA to autofill all of these rows.

The formula in Cell H280 is the following:
=PISampDat(Sheet1!$T$3,"2019-05-01","2019-06-01","1h",2,Sheet3!$B$280)

This is replicated in all cells up through ABX280 (values for each hour in the month of May, and including midnight of June 1, 2019.)

I don't know where to start in VBA.

I have tried getting rid of the $ before the 280, but then I am prompted "You are not allowed to change part of an array."

Attempts to copy the formula into other lines results in the message "Resize to show all values", but resizing and recalculating does nothing. Either that, or I'm just copying the values from other lines and the formula isn't actually getting called for other data items.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need VBA to achieve this.  PISampDat uses an [array formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) so you can either refresh it by using Ctrl+Shift+Enter or by re-opening the function wizard to re-enter a bigger range for the parameter locations.

To go further I'd suggest to use the following resource: [Creating Basic Reports with PI Datalink](https://pisquare.osisoft.com/community/Learn-PI/creating-basic-reports-with-PI-DataLink)